# float and display affection on width and height

Tags: css, html, css-float

What is the effect of inline and block and inline-block and floating to width and height?

For example take look at below css menu :

```
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:Blue;
    padding:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
ul li{display:inline;}
ul li a
{
    /*display:inline-block;
    float:left;*/
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    background-color:rgb(100,170,110);
    color:Yellow;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
ul li a:hover{background-color:Yellow;color:Red;}
```

I have corrected that for both IE and Firefox with adding below codes for ul:

```
display:inline-block;
float:left;
```

Is it true that for a inline tag the height=0?

Is it true for the left floated tag , it width is the maximum widths of it's children ?

Why block elements (such as menu items) will have some margins with their next items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get some goofy stuff with inline-block with IE. You might have better luck setting tha a's to block and float the li's. Try the code below

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
li { float: left; }
a { display: block; padding: 5px; margin: 0 5px; }
```

Comment: but you didnot answer me fully